# Separate declaration from definition of array of int in java

Tags: java, android

How can i seperate declartion of array of int, from definition?. Sorry for basic questions. i m basically from c/c++ background.

```
int [] res;

switch (something) 
{
  case <something>:
     res = somefunction () 
     break;
{

if ( res == null )  ==>> problem is here. // 'res' might not have been initialized.
```

How can i handle this, and what is the best approach?

Comment: It could be nice, if why down voting for this question?. that would help me to correct myself to post the question in better way in feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the array variable (or for that matter, any variable) is a local variable, you must give it an initial value, since local variables don't have default values.

```
int [] res = null;
```

This way it will have a value even if your case statement is not executed.

Answer (score 6):

As the other answers mentioned, you can do

```
int [] res = null;
```

but I frequently prefer to make sure the `switch` handles all cases:

```
int [] res;                   // Leave it uninitialized

// ...

switch (something)            // Set `res` in every branch
{
  case <something>:
     res = somefunction();
     break;
  // ...
  default:                    // Including the default
     res = null;
     break;
}
```

That way, if you add a new condition, you have to consciously decide what you should do with `res` (since if you don't do anything, the compiler will remind you).

There are use cases for both the pre-init and the "handle it in all paths" approaches.

Answer (score 3):

So, initialize

```
int [] res = null;
```